# Identify records with different values after partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to identify records partitioned based on Import Number and Part Number but select only where Classification column has different values within this partition.

In the below sample, the first 4 rows have different Class so I would like to select only these records. The last 2 rows have the same class so they should be filtered out.

| Import No | Part No | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1AU6006 | ET7109 | US |
| 1AU6006 | ET7109 | GEN |
| 1AU6007 | ET7110 | US |
| 1AU6007 | ET7110 | GEN |
| 1AU6512 | ET7115 | US |
| 1AU6512 | ET7115 | US |

I am not sure on how to figure out this logic so I do not have any starting code.

Comment: Your sample table is missing a column which generates the _order_ you perceive to exist.  We need a column to order the data the way you see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analytic count over your partition columns:

```
select import_no, part_no, class,
  count(distinct class) over (partition by import_no, part_no) as class_count
from your_table;

IMPORT_NO PART_NO CLASS CLASS_COUNT
--------- ------- ----- -----------
1AU6006   ET7109  GEN             2
1AU6006   ET7109  US              2
1AU6007   ET7110  GEN             2
1AU6007   ET7110  US              2
1AU6512   ET7115  US              1
1AU6512   ET7115  US              1
```

and then use that in a subquery or CTE to filter out the rows where that count is only 1:

```
select import_no, part_no, class
from (
  select import_no, part_no, class,
    count(distinct class) over (partition by import_no, part_no) as class_count
  from your_table
)
where class_count > 1;

IMPORT_NO PART_NO CLASS
--------- ------- -----
1AU6006   ET7109  GEN  
1AU6006   ET7109  US   
1AU6007   ET7110  GEN  
1AU6007   ET7110  US
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=575bb55d4c8486ea86431894a39c2afa)

Answer (score 0):

You might find that `exists` works well for this:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.import_no = t.import_no and
                    t2.part_no = t.part_no and
                    t2.class <> t.class
             );
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `(import_no, part_no, class)`.

Note:  You could also use aggregation, if you are willing to get two rows in the result set:

```
select import_no, part_no,
       listagg(class, ',') within group (order by class) as classes
from t
group by import_no, part_no;
```